# Get two lower bytes from int variable

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I have some data in `int` variables in Java (range between 0 and 64000). How to convert to byte this integer? I need just two lower bytes from `int` (range is ok). How to extract this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can get the lowest byte from the integer by ANDing with `0xFF`:

```
byte lowByte = (byte)(value & 0xFF);
```

This works because `0xFF` has zero bits everywhere above the first byte.

To get the second-lowest-byte, you can repeat this trick after shifting down all the bits in the number 8 spots:

```
byte penultimateByte = (byte)((value >> 8) & 0xFF);
```

Comment: +1 although it's not a trick, it's called "arithmetic shift" ;-)

Comment: I get negative values, when the value is greater than 127. Can we do anything for that?

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to do AND operation to get the lower byte just cast it to the byte and get the lower byte in the byte variable.

try following both will give you same result

```
short value = 257;
System.out.println(value);
byte low = (byte) value;
System.out.println("low: " + low);
byte high = (byte)(value >> 8);
System.out.println("high: " + high);

value = 257;
System.out.println(value);
low = (byte) (value & 0xFF);
System.out.println("low: " + low);
high = (byte) ((value >> 8) & 0xFF);
System.out.println("high: " + high);
```

or try it on [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/V0mrsx)